# Dedication of my thesis to my late father

Tags: sentence-choice

My father passed away when I was studying my PhD. Now I want to dedicate my thesis to him. I want to say that I am afraid that I couldn't finish my studies sooner. How do you feel about something like "a late thesis to the memory of my father"? Or "To my father who couldn't wait to see his doctor son"? The latter sound funny, I think. What's your suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word *late* can be used as a respectful adjective meaning *deceased*, so you could say:

> a late thesis to the memory of my father

or:

> a thesis to the memory of my late father

or even:

> a late thesis to the memory of my late father

That last one has a little wordplay, but I think it's only mildly humorous, yet it manages to stay serious and respectful as well.

---

As for the second:

> To my father who couldn't wait to see his doctor son

the phrase *couldn't wait* usually means, "be very excited about;" and it makes me think of things like schoolchildren who *can't wait* for the last day of school, or distant lovers who *can't wait* to be reunited. I think it's a bit awkward in this context, because it almost sounds like you're bitter he couldn't live long enough to see you graduate (and I don't think that's what you're trying to say). Maybe you're trying to say something like this?

> To my late father, who unfortunately didn't stay in this world long enough to see his son become a doctor.

I hope this helps. Sorry for your loss, but congratulations on your academic accomplishments.